# Transpiling es7 to es6 error unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, transpiler

I have transpiled a javascript code from es7 to es6 since I need to use

> Node.js 6.9.5

but I keep getting this error when transpiling:

**Unexpected Identifier keyValues[key] = yield *DbStorage.get(key);***

my code looks like this:

```
getMany: function (keys) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let keyValues = {};

        for(let key of keys){
            keyValues[key] = await DbStorage.get(key);
        }

        resolve(keyValues);
    });
},
```

and the transpiled code looks like this:

```
 getMany: function (keys) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let keyValues = {};
        for (let key of keys) {
            keyValues[key] = yield DbStorage.get(key);
        }
        resolve(keyValues);
    });
},
```

I am using typescript to transpile my tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
"allowJs" : true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "listFiles" : false,
    "diagnostics" : false, 
    "outDir" : "build",
    "allowJs" : true,
    "inlineSourceMap" : false
},
"include" : ["collaboration/*"],
"exclude": [ "build", "node_modules" ]
```

}

so what's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `await` in a non-`async` function, which is incorrect. `getMany` should be `async`, which amongst other things means you don't need `new Promise`:

```
getMany: async function (keys) {
//       ^^^^^
    let keyValues = {};

    for (let key of keys){
        keyValues[key] = await DbStorage.get(key);
    }

    return keyValues;
},
```

It's very strange of the TypeScript compiler to turn that erroneous `await` into an erroneous `yield`, but it could be an edge-case bug in the TypeScript compiler. If you fix the usage, hopefully it will transpile correctly.

Comment: ah thank you T.J. Crowder, for the good answer yes it did got transpiled very good. Do you suggest using another transpiler ?

Comment: @gentos It isn't a bug in TypeScript. TypeScript has two "phases", the compile phase (which is the type and syntax checking) and the transpile phase (which is just emitting target code). You somehow skipped the compile stage and completely ignored the errors.

Comment: @gentos It does, how do you call TypeScript? A loader? `tsc`? Directly from Node?

Comment: @gentos: Not if you're using TypeScript for its type features, no. But do pay attention to the error messages. TypeScript's compiler emits code even when there are errors (at least in some cases, I'm not a TS expert), so it's important to check those errors.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha no I am calling through the terminal via: tsc and than doing a watch via: tsc -w